# Content not appear in body

Tags: javascript

I have a file `a.html`, which has the following content:

```
<script>
var x=document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
document.write(x);  
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
<body>

</body>
```

When I am browsing to `a.html#somevalueh;alert(1)</script>`, why only `"somevalueh;alert(1)"` but not the `</script>` portion  appeared inside the body?

I am using chrome btw.

Comment: what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I did not expect this kind of question from your reputation.

Comment: @argentum47 question updated

Comment: @codehx question updated

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `</script>` tag has special meaning for the browser and it is has the opening tag, so it is silently droping it.

Try escaping the url to get the hint like this:

```
<script>
var x=document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1);
document.write(escape(x));  
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
</script>
<body>

</body>
```

This will give you the output:

```
somevalueh%3Balert%281%29%3C/script%3E
```

escaping the special characters.

***update:***
you may also want to try this. 
Just using your html as it is change `somevalueh;alert(1)</script>` to `somevalueh;<script>alert(1)</script>`

And then inspect your page, you must see the `<script></script>` with in your body tag.